# How to configure apache/magento2 to be able to reach the /setup when /pub is configured as root?

Tags: configuration, setup, apache, web-setup-wizard

How to configure apache/magento2 to be able to reach the /setup when /pub is configured as root?

When i configure apache to use /pub as root i can't access the web-setup-wizard.

Does someone have a solution for this?

/Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this by creating symbolic links, this would of course only work on a Linux server. Something along the lines of:

```
cd magento_root/
ln -s ../setup/ pub/setup
```

You will have to create links for other (publicly) required directories too, I believe `app/` and `update/`.

Comment: Thanks benjamin. I ended up adding two Alias in my <VirtualHost/> for /setup and /update and that seem to work.

Comment: Great, nice solution!